# How to get an Uri on a file saved in app private storage?

Tags: android

I have to write an image in the private storage of my app. I do that this way:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILE_FRONT_PROCESSED_IMAGE_CACHE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
mFrontBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
fos.close();
```

My question is : Is it possible to get / forge an Uri pointing to this file ? (i found many solutions with external storage, but impossible to find out how to achieve this with private app storage)

EDIT (with CommonsWare advices) :

```
private Uri saveTempImage(Bitmap bitmap, String filename)
{
    File cache = new File(getFilesDir(), filename);
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cache);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return Uri.fromFile(cache);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to get / forge an Uri pointing to this file ?

If you [use `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), you can [get a `content://` `Uri` for a file](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#GetUri).

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but to use FileProvider it appears that i still need a File object. If i had one, i would have got an Uri by calling Uri.fromFile(File).

Comment: @Poilaupat: Don't use `openFileOutput()`. Use `getFilesDir()` and create your `FileOutputStream` from there.

Comment: That was the point ! It seems it's not possible to get an uri without having a handler on the file. So, as you said, I shouldn't create the file by openFileOutput(). I used  getFilesDir() instead (which also goes to the private app storage). I'll edit my question with the modified code.